# How to convert the current date to a numeric value in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Example: i like to convert the currentdate into a numeric value like YYYYMMDD.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following formula 
`tonumber(totext(currentdate,'yyyyMMdd'))` 
This formula will convert your Current Date to YYYYMMDD format and the field will be a Numeric Field. 
Hope this helps !!

Comment: You don't need the extra set of parentheses.